# How do I use the inputbox to add info to a batch file that sends emails and require a password to send?

Tags: email, batch-file, vbscript

I've got this code from here and it works great to create and send:

```
:: email.bat :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
setlocal

:: use these settings to send from a gmail account
:: set port=465 and set SSL=True

:: use these settings for standard email SMTP port and no encryption
:: set port=25 and set SSL=False

:: Change these following items to use the same variables all the time
:: or use the command line to pass all the variables

set Port=25
set SSL=False
set From="myemail@myemailserver.com"
set To="recipient@server.com"
set Subject="Subject line"
set Body="Email Body in one line"
set SMTPServer="mailservername.myemailserver.com"
set User="username"
set Pass="password"
set fileattach="d:\myfolder\file.txt"

:: This section sets the command line arguments
:: use this format:  CALL email.bat "myname@gmail.com" "RecipientEmailAddress@server.com" "Subject line" "Email Body in one line" "smtp.gmail.com"  "myname@gmail.com" "password" "d:\folder\filename to attach.txt"

if "%~7" NEQ "" (
  set From="%~1"
  set To="%~2"
  set Subject="%~3"
  set Body="%~4"
  set SMTPServer="%~5"
  set User="%~6"
  set Pass="%~7"
  set fileattach="%~8"
)

set "vbsfile=%temp%\email-bat.vbs"
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
set cdoSchema=http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objArgs       = WScript.Arguments
echo >>"%vbsfile%" Set objEmail      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.From     = %From%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.To       = %To%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Subject  = %Subject%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Textbody = %body%
if exist %fileattach% echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.AddAttachment %fileattach%
echo >>"%vbsfile%" with objEmail.Configuration.Fields
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusing")        = 2 ' not local, smtp
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserver")       = %SMTPServer%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpserverport")   = %port%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpauthenticate") = 1 ' cdobasic
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendusername")     = %user%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/sendpassword")     = %pass%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpusessl")       = %SSL%
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Item ("%cdoSchema%/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30
echo >>"%vbsfile%"  .Update
echo >>"%vbsfile%" end with
echo >>"%vbsfile%" objEmail.Send

cscript.exe /nologo "%vbsfile%"
echo email sent (if variables were correct)
del "%vbsfile%" 2>nul
goto :EOF
```

and I found this bit for the input GUI:

```
@echo off
REM Input routine for batch using VBScript to provide input box
REM Stephen Knight, October 2009, http://www.dragon-it.co.uk/

call :inputbox "Please enter something for me:" "Box Title"
echo You entered %Input%

exit /b

:InputBox
set input=
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo wscript.echo inputbox(WScript.Arguments(0),WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"') do set input=%%a
exit /b
```

All of the info in the email is static the to, from, subject, username, password and smtp except the body which I need the user input from the input box for. The user response for the body of the email will be exactly 12 characters. I have the input box script modified to display what I want for the input, but I dont know how to put it all into one file and pass the input over to the VBScript file.

Comment: Why go through the batch file route?

Comment: What @Mike said. When your batch code does nothing except generating and calling a VBScript you're better off writing and running the VBScript directly.

Comment: im a noob sorry guys. ok so heres what im attempting so you can better undrstand what im working on... i have a bat file that calls vbs to open inputbox... this asks the user for the msra password generated by the first batch file i have that opens the msra and saves the invitation to the destop i need to pas that to mailing bat body which is set to attach that invitatation to an email that is set to come to me... then  another input box that asks a passphrase which i want to hold up the email. easier ways to ask for remote assistance but i just want to make my own... does this make any sense?

Comment: the passphrase that stops the email unless correct isnt for any security issues its just some novelty i decided to put in it asks a stupid question. i want it to message the user if they got it wrong and inform them the message was sent if the got it right. its for me to give my friends that are always asking for help and i just want my own custom way to request it oh and i want to convert it to an exe... silly and pointless project but im enjoying the knowledge and experience im gaining.

Comment: Oh and FYI I've spent about 3 hours a day for the last week researching and watching videos to get this far. I have a stack of test runs and edits to send for anyone who might think otherwise. I only uploaded 2 of the examples I've referenced for info. I also apoligize for my initial question of passing user input from the inputbox to a VBS that sends emails and requiring a password being "unclear". I appreciate any and all help and advice I can get. BTW Thank you for your input @ Ansgar Wiechers @Mike! This is the first forum in general that I have ever posted a question about anything on.

Answer (score 0):

To use a batch file input routine, Enter the required details in the lines below (which are already in the script) and add the last two lines shown.

```
set Port=25
set SSL=False
set From="myemail@myemailserver.com"
set To="recipient@server.com"
set Subject="Subject line"
REM set Body="Email Body in one line"
set SMTPServer="mailservername.myemailserver.com"
set User="username"
set Pass="password"
set fileattach="d:\myfolder\file.txt"
set /p "Body=Enter the 12 characters here: "
set Body="%body%"
```